# Is getClass() method static in java?

Tags: java

The getClass() method is defined as this in Java API:

```
public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

However, I saw others' code like this and it works:

```
private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
```

I tried to use the above line in my own code, then I received this complaint:

```
"Can't make a static reference from a non-static method() from the type Object"
```

It should be objectName.getClass(), right? I am wondering why the 'logger' definition is valid.

Comment: Give the context, the modifiers on your method, the class it's in.  Just telling us that you did the same thing doesn't mean it's actually the same.

Comment: Slightly different. I added a 'static' to my definition. Everything else is the same.

Comment: Ah, but that makes all the difference in the world...

Comment: Why can't I call a instance method (myClass.getClass()) in a static definition? For example, in static void main() {}, you typically create instances of objects and then use them.

Comment: @user697911 If you want to call an instance method in a static definition, you can, but you'd need to create the instance just like you said.

Comment: You can absolutely call `someObject.getClass()` in a static context. That's entirely different from `getClass()` which is `this.getClass()`.

Comment: @Radiodef, Doesn't 'this' mean the current object of the current class?

Comment: Yes...so you can't call `this.getClass()` in a static context, because there is no `this`.

Comment: You might also wanna look into aspect oriented programming. It helps prevent mixing your logging with your application's business logic. Check out [cross-cutting concerns](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-cutting_concern)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getClass` is not static, so from a static context, use `MyClass.class` syntax, and from a non-static context, use `getClass()` syntax:

```
public class MyClass {
  public Logger getLogger() { return LogFactory.getLog(getClass()); }

  public static Logger getLogger() { return LogFactory.getLog(MyClass.class); }
}
```

Comment: In what situations that we would need a logger for each instance? Logger should log for an entire application, not a particular class instance? Otherwise, how many logger instances you need to create, and what's the usefulness of them?

Comment: You wouldn't. This is only to show the difference in syntax.

Comment: Is there a big performance difference? because I did see the non-static version of the logger, as shown in the question.

Comment: The JVM is able to dispatch static methods faster than instance methods. Also, it's better to make everything static that you're able to, since it indicates that the value/algorithm doesn't depend on/mutate instance values. But I certainly wouldn't alter a design just to try to make something static. I've never worried about the performance difference between static and instance dispatch.

Comment: The main question I have is, why the open source library I am using is using a non-static logger. I suspect the author made a sort of mistake there?

Comment: An exception in Javaland that's common is to use instance values because it's easier to inject and test than statics. But unless the logger in question could actually vary, it seems to be a simple coding error. I always coded logs in Java as `private static final Logger log = LogFactory.getLogger(MyClass.class);`

Answer (score 2):

It's valid if it's `private final` and not `private static final`, because if it's `private final` then it's allocated for a specific object; it's implicitly equivalent to `LogFactory.getLog(this.getClass())`.

Comment: I see. what definition is better? Maybe 'static' version is better?

Comment: @user697911 it depends on what you need.  For this situation `static` is probably more suited to logging, since you don't need a different logger for every instance of the class; you'll just have to initialize it differently (e.g. by passing in `MyClass.class`).

Answer (score 1):

A field declaration goes like this:

```
modifiers type name = initializer;
```

One of the possible modifiers is `static`. It's a very significant modifier - a static field belongs to the *class*. It is created and initialized when the class is loaded, before any actual objects are created. You can use it without having any instance of the class at all, just by using `Classname.name`.

If the field is not static, it is created and initialized when the object is created, just prior to running the code in the constructor.

This means that the *initializer* for static field is ran at class creation time, without any instance of the class, whereas an initializer of a non-static field is ran after an instance has been created. Hence, when a static field's initializer is ran, you don't have a `this` and you can't use non-static methods, which require a `this` in respect with which to run.

So you can't run `getClass()` in static context. It's supposed to go to the `this` object, and run the native code that, given the object, gets a reference to the `class` object associated with it. Not having an object, you can't run that.

But at static initialization time you can just use a class literal. So, if your class is called `Foo`, you can use `Foo.class`. That's a class literal.

If you want your logger to be static (one logger, shared by all instances of that class, created before any instance of the class exists), then you'll need to pass it the class literal.

```
private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(Foo.class);
```

If you want each of your instances to have its own logger object, you will need to remove the `static` modifier, and use the code as in the given example.